# ICE Failed when using Firefox for Android after first call

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, webrtc, firefox-android

On some devices (specially Samsung) I have found the following error while establishing a P2P connection:

> Error processing ICE candidate-
>   Failed to set remote offer sdp: The order of m-lines in subsequent offer doesn't match order from previous offer/answer

If I establish the connection for the first time it works perfectly but if I try it a second time it fails until I wait some time, even if I force the P2P connection to close. This does not happen with Chrome for Android or every device.

My code before setting an Ice candidate:

```
    var candidate = new RTCIceCandidate({
        sdpMLineIndex: evt.sdpMLineIndex,
        sdpMid       : evt.sdpMid,
        candidate    : evt.candidate
    });
    peerConn.addIceCandidate(candidate, onSuccess, onFailure);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I wasn't cutting the local stream properly which made the camera and microphone look like they were still in use.

```
 if(localstream){
        localstream.getTracks()[0].stop();
        localstream = null;
    }
```

I think Samsung's layer makes Firefox act differently as it only happened on the Samsung devices from all the devices I tested.